# 2 tasks running in parallel, but one finishes work and waits for the other to complete

Tags: parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

This is an extension to the solution in [2 Async tasks in parallel and waiting for results - .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460849/2-async-tasks-in-parallel-and-waiting-for-results-net/31461027#31461027)

The methods of the two tasks are:

```
Private Sub tempWorker1()
  For i = 1 To 50000
     If i Mod 100 = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("From 1:{0}", i)
     End If
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub tempWorker2()
  For i = 1 To 1000
     If i Mod 100 = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("From 2:{0}", i)
     End If
  Next
End Sub
```

The calling methods are:

```
Dim task1 As Task = Task.Run(AddressOf tempWorker1)
Dim task2 As Task = Task.Run(AddressOf tempWorker2)
Await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).ConfigureAwait(False)
```

Now, I'd need to have `task1` and `task2` run in parallel but `task1` should not be over until `task2` is complete. And the entire process should wait for both the tasks to complete.

Is there a way to achieve this using TPL. Or do I need to bank on global variables to stop `task1` from finishing until `task2` sets the global variable?

I am aware of `ContinueWith` but that would defeat parallelism with the tasks running one after the other - which is not the requirement.

Comment: If I understand correct, the code in your `tempWorker1()` and `tempWorker2()` are dummy code; in your actual code, `tempWorker1()` would have a need to use the results computed by `tempWorker2()` in the middle of its execution, but the two functions should be allowed to execute in parallel before that point is reached. Am I right? If not, please revise your description and code example to better illustrate why you need `task1` to be "not over until `task2` is complete".

Comment: Yes you are right. They are dummy code and `tempWorker1()` would need to use results from `tempWorker2()`. And yes, the two functions should be allowed to execute in parallel before that point is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd need to have task1 and task2 run in parallel but task1 should not be over until task2 is complete.

So, just start `task2` first, then pass `task2` into `tempWorker1`:

```
Dim task2 As Task = Task.Run(AddressOf tempWorker2)
Dim task1 As Task = Task.Run(Function() tempWorker1(task2))
```

And have `tempWorker1` call `Await task2` when it needs the value.

Comment: Thx Stephen. Makes sense. Wonder why I didn't catch that :-) Long way to got to understand TPL.